# Missing permissions required by FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

> I have been learning this map in kotlin but **mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true** and **fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->}** are throwing same error as user-permission for
> **Missing permissions required by FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission**

> ***my MapActivity class is shown bellow***

````
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var lastLocation: Location



    companion object {
        private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)

        setUpMap()
    }

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker): Boolean = false

    private fun setUpMap(){

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }

        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if (location != null){
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLng)
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 12f))
            }
        }

    }

    private fun placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLng: LatLng) {

    }

} ```

> *** AndroidMenifest.xml as shown below ***

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MapInKotlin"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <!--
             TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

             To get one, follow the directions here:

                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

             Once you have your API key (it starts with "AIza"), define a new property in your
             project's local.properties file (e.g. MAPS_API_KEY=Aiza...), and replace the
             "YOUR_API_KEY" string in this file with "${MAPS_API_KEY}".
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
````

Comment: At runtime you request only fine location.

Answer (score 1):

You're only checking and requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.

You have to request both of them. One way of doing that is by creating array of permissions:

```
requestMultiplePermissions.launch(arrayOf(
    Manifest.permission.ACESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
    Manifest.permission.ACESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
```

And requesting them with ActivityResultContract then depending on the result do something with `fusedLocationClient`.

Check out [ActivityResultContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContract)

Comment: In this case you cannot use an array. You have to request them separately and one after the other.

Comment: Why not? @blackapps
I tested it out and it works fine for me when requesting them at the same time.

Comment: On an Android 12+ device too?

Comment: ```if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),  LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }```  **Still showing the same error**

Comment: Use `ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions` with the constructed array.